# Added Thinktecture Identity Manger package via NuGet - now how to I access the admin panel?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity-2, thinktecture

I added Thinktecture Identity Manager via Nuget. Now what do i do next? All the of the screen caps I have seen show access to the admin panel via utr like `http://localhost:17457/#/list'

That's what i see at Hanselman's blog and also over at Brock's site. I added the nuget package to an existing site also so don't know if that makes a difference.

So the question, how exactly do i navigate to the admin panel? I have searched high and low and not found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://localhost:17457/admin ?
If you mapped idsrv on root.

Take a look: http://cedric-dumont.com/tutorials/identityserver-v3-membershipreboot-angularjs-webapi-2-and-mvc-mix-it-introduction/identityserver-v3-membershipreboot-angularjs-webapi-2-and-mvc-mix-it-part-1/